# How to make a delete button permanently delete.

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

So heres how this works so far,the index page allows you to create a game. Games are then posted onto /data/games ( Gamelist.html). I want to have a button that permanently deletes the games from the list. I currently have a remove button but it doesnt do anything.

Index( create games from here)

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Planning Poker</title>
<style>
    .inlinetext {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#button').on('click', function (data) {
            $.post('data/games/create/?title=5', function (d) { console.log(d) });
        })
    });
</script>
</head>



<body>
<h3 class='inlinetext'> Create Game: </h3>
    <input type="text" id="testtext" name="ime">
    <button id="button" >Create</button>


  </body>

 </html>
```

Controller

```
 using PlanningPoker.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace PlanningPoker.Controllers
{
public class GMController : ApiController
{
    private static List<Game> games = new List<Game>() {
            new Game() {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Title = "D&D"
            }
        };

    [Route("data/games")]
    public IEnumerable<Game> GetAllGames() {
        return games;
    }

    [Route("data/games/create"), HttpPost]
    public Guid CreateGame(string title) {
        Game g = new Game() {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Title = title
        };

        games.Add(g);

        return g.ID;
    }
}
}
```

Gamelist(html)

```
  <title>Game List</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="Gamelist.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

            <h4>Games</h4>

            <ul data-bind="foreach: $data.games">
                <li>
                    Game <span data-bind="text: $index"> </span>:
                    <span data-bind="text: Title"> </span>
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeGame">Remove</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button data-bind="click: addGame">Add</button>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Gamlist (javascript)

```
function AppViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.games = ko.observableArray([]);

$.getJSON("/data/games", function (d) {
    self.games(d);
});

self.addGame = function () {
    self.game.push({ name: "Created On " + new Date() });
};

self.removeGame = function () {
    self.game.remove(this);
}
}
$(function () {
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```

Comment: please use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something else...

Comment: ... in addition to putting your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Knockout will automatically pass back the current item as a parameter in the click event binding...

```
self.removeGame = function(game) {
    self.games.remove(game);
}
```

Comment: also, be aware that in your js example, you're working with self.game instead of self.games...

Comment: it deletes, but when i hit refresh its still there. I want it to be gone for ever once i hit delete

Comment: well, yeah...you have to also remove it from your data source. You'll need to trigger an async call in the self.removeGame method to your routed GMController

Comment: how would i go about triggering that

Comment: similar to how you are initializing your application. in the removeGame method, call your $.getJSON method and pass it the game to remove. in your controller or service call, handle the removal of the game from your persistent data. as it stands now, you'll always have D&D as a game since it's just a static parameter in your controller.

Comment: Is there anyway you could show me an example of how to do it? Im pretty new to writing code and dont completely follow how to do it. Thanks for your patience

Comment: I'd be happy to, however you currently aren't showing anything that leads me to knowing how your data is stored nor how you access it. Right now, you've just got a static List of games. Do you have a preferred way of storing your data? SQL? MySQL? NoSQL? ;)